# Google tag manager collect the data from other domains?

Tags: google-tag-manager

After using Goole Tag Manager from Goole Analystics it starts to collect the visitor info from other domains that even don't have the tag. These domains share same IP address but it shouldn't be the problem I guess. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many problems. Lets look at it:

1. do you manage the other pages?
2. is it possible you accidentally deployed the tag to this domains?
3. is it possible that you maybe accidently didnt change the UA-ID in
   the tag you deployed?
4. check them with Google Tag Assistant extension installed and enabled
   in Google Chrome for Google Tag Manager tag, its really on the page? see 3) with what UA-ID?
5. is there maybe standard Google Analytics tracking left on the other
   domains?

Let me know I would like to dig into your problem and help it fix it. It really looks like some previous tag was forgotten on the other domains. There is no way how domain without any tag could appear in your GA, except of course the traffic spam bots, which can be filtered.

In that case refer to this page http://help.analyticsedge.com/spam-filter/definitive-guide-to-removing-google-analytics-spam/ which is kept up to date. Especially focus on Valid Hostname filter, but be careful with the deployment. Always preview, debug and test, before putting in into your main view in GA.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix it by relying on Goole Tag Assistant extention.